# How can I color middle 3 divs only using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>test1</div>
        <div>test2</div>
        <div class="middle">test3</div>
        <div>test4</div>
        <div>test5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above example how can i color only text2, text3 and text4

Comment: Possibly but it depends on whether is actually asking for "all but first and last" or just middle three...which is an entirely dfferent question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted your question.  Do you mean "all but first and last"?  If so, then my answer works (or if you only have 5 divs...).  Otherwise use [mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31750609/3076272).

Select all divs that are children of the container, except for the first and last one.

```js
$('.container > div').not(':first').not(':last').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>text 1</div>
    <div>text 2</div>
    <div>text 3</div>
    <div>text 4</div>
    <div>text 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not QUITE what is asked. He wants the middle ones

Comment: @mplungjan that isn't how I read it, although you saying that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use prev and next with [addBack](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)

```js
$('.middle').next().addBack().prev().addBack().css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div class="middle">test3</div>
    <div>test4</div>
    <div>test5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is beyond the scope of the question, what would you do with an even number of divs?

Comment: Good question. Not this :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the best methods in jQuery to select a sequence of elements is the `slice()` method. Very easy and concise -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div div div').slice(1,4).css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>test1</div>
        <div>test2</div>
        <div class="middle">test3</div>
        <div>test4</div>
        <div>test5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not very intuitive. What exactly is going on?